# What is the set of CouchDB specific global variables?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, global

Looking for the specific set of global variables that are available in CouchDB so that I can help JSHint create a configuration to ignore them:

https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/issue/9

Right now the list that I have is: emit, log, getRow, start, send, require.

I couldn't find this anywhere on the CouchDB wiki, or my wiki-fu is weakening >.<

Answer (score 4):

While the CouchDB documentation is improving rapidly, I'm not sure when this will be covered. You are probably better off looking at the source code. If you know Javascript, it is very easy to understand.

Here is the [variable bindings in the CouchDB view server](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/server/loop.js#L20-30). That covers (I think!) all of the variables except `require` which is in [util.js](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/share/server/util.js#L83).

At the time of this writing, those are:

- emit
- getRow
- isArray
- JSON
- log
- provides
- registerType
- require
- send
- start
- sum
- toJSON

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that JSHint includes "Environment" options that bundle together globals in various environments. For example, the [couch option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#couch) covers globals for CouchDB.